# Android adapter arrayadapter or cursor?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have to set `ListView` and to fill it by data. I have bitmaps in external storage and name of that bitmaps in table, also I have other data in sqlite beside name of bitmap.

The mechanism is following. I have to get from table name add to path and load bitmap, also with other data from table for specific row.
Which adapter you can recommend me to use?

I tried with `CursorAdapter` but didn't get success because I have problem with loading and repeating images in `ListView`.

Here is part of my code:

```
holder.pic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.adapterInterPicture);

holder.picIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BaseHelper.PIC_DATE);
holder.picCheck = cursor.getString(holder.picIndex);
holder.imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/imagesGallery/"+ holder.picCheck + ".jpg";
holder.options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
holder.options.inSampleSize = 8;
holder.bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(holder.imagePath,holder.options); 

After that in bind view I use the folllowing code:
if(holder.bitmap1 == null){holder.pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.intermediate_pic);
}
if(holder.bitmap1 != null){
holder.pic.setImageBitmap(holder.bitmap1);
}
```

Comment: For SQLite use a cursor adapter.

Comment: But have problem to load bitmaps is there any alternative?

Comment: Use cursor adapter and e.g. Picasso library to load the image based on path from DB.

Comment: @user3572787 You never told us what you did to load the image so we can't tell you what you did wrong. Update your question.

Comment: Then ask another question about loading bitmaps..

Comment: Here is my question about that problem, sadly no one coudn't give me tha answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677204/custom-cursor-adapter-and-bitmap-from-external-sources

Comment: Your issue is with the image loading method, not with the adapter.
Post the code used to load images.